# make: *** [makefile.unix:193: obj/rpcclient.o] Error 1

Tags: linux, shell, compilation, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile a Stratis wallet just by doing "make" command. I have this error :

```
make: *** [makefile.unix:193: obj/rpcclient.o] Error 1
```

I searched on the internet but I have not idea what is the problem...

Comment: The actual error is higher up in the log so you need to look for that.